# ipfs files ls does not seem to work configured as a private network

Tags: ipfs

When configured as a private network, "ipfs files ls" does not return anything (although many files are loaded and visible through the webui for that particular peer.  It does work fine when the network is public.  The nodejs client ipfs.files.ls does not return anything either. Is this due to some mis-configuration of my node?  Any way around this? Thanks.

Comment: curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/files/ls returns {"Entries":null}

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I cannot seem to reproduce that behaviour on my end, what version of IPFS are you running?

Here's what I did to setup a private network, with a working MFS (fresh install):

### Init IPFS repo

```sh
ipfs init
```

### Generate swarm key

```sh
go get github.com/Kubuxu/go-ipfs-swarm-key-gen/ipfs-swarm-key-gen
cd ~/go/bin/
./ipfs-swarm-key-gen > ~/.ipfs/swarm.key
```

### Remove default bootstrap

```sh
ipfs bootstrap rm --all
```

### Add new bootstrap (if needed)

```sh
ipfs bootstrap add <multiaddr>
```

### Edit systemd service to enforce private network (path may vary)

Add `Environment="LIBP2P_FORCE_PNET=1"` underneath `[Service]`

```sh
sudo vim /usr/lib/systemd/user/ipfs.service
```

### Start IPFS daemon

```sh
systemctl --user start ipfs
```

### Check MFS

```sh
ipfs files ls /
```

No output, because we just initialised

### Add file to MFS

```sh
echo "Hello world" > hello
ipfs add hello
ipfs files cp /ipfs/QmePw8gVcBMb8x6kAep6aMBAX23hCSk6iZW3i9VKkiFhu1 /hello
```

### Check MFS again

```sh
ipfs files ls /
```

Correctly reports `hello`

### Verify private network is indeed being used

```sh
systemctl --user stop ipfs
mv ~/.ipfs/swarm.key ~/.ipfs/swarm.key.bk
systemctl --user start ipfs
systemctl --user status ipfs
```

You should see the daemon has failed to start, if private network is being enforced.

### Move private key back

```sh
mv ~/.ipfs/swarm.key.bk ~/.ipfs/swarm.key
```